# If $|y_m| \to 0$ then there exists $k_m$ such that $k_m |y_m| \to t$

Tags: real-analysis

> **Lemma 3.43**
>   Suppose $B_m$ are elements of $G$ and that $B_m \to I$.
>   Let $Y_m = \log B_m$, which is defined for all sufficiently large $m$.
>   Suppose that $Y_m$ is nonzero for all $m$ and that $Y_m/\|Y_m\| \to Y \in \operatorname{M}_n(\mathbb{C})$.
>   Then $Y$ is in $\mathfrak{g}$.
>
> *Proof.*
>   For any $t \in \mathbb{R}$, we have $(t/\|Y_m\|)Y_m \to t Y$.
>   Note that since $B_m \to I$, we have $\|Y_m\| \to 0$.
>   Thus, we can find integers $k_m$ such that $k_m \|Y_m\| \to t$.
>   We have, then,
>   $$
>       e^{k_m Y_m}
>   =   \exp
>       \left[
>         (k_m \|Y_m\|) \frac{Y_m}{\|Y_m\|}
>       \right]
>   \to e^{tY}.
> $$
>
> (Original image [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JAsK8.jpg).)

The group $G$ is a Lie group of matrices. This was taken from Brian Hall. It’s reallly just analysis question. But I’m not entirely sure why the $k_m$’s exists

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You see, $Y_m \neq 0$ for all large $m$ so $\|Y_m\| \neq 0$. Just set $k_m = t/\|Y_m\|$.

Then $k_m\|Y_m\| = t$.

Comment: Ah okay thanks.

Comment: But $k_m$s may not be integers in this case.